# Efficient procedural, instanced mesh rendering in Unreal using structured buffers

Tags: unreal, procedural

I need to render some procedural, instanced data in unreal. I have a mesh and a structured buffer (if that parlance is unknown in unreal land - a big GPU buffer of arbitrary data) full of instance data, pose data and so on describing position and variations in blend shapes, skin tone, overlays and so on I want to render an army of characters using an instanced draw call.

I have this running in unity and opengl and now I need to get the same system to run in Unreal.

I am very green in unreal development and it doesn't seem straightforward to do this nor is it easy to find a path that looks relevant in the documentation. Most of what I need to do is vertex shader based which, as  far as I can tell, means the material graph is out of the window. Therefore I think I need  a 'global shader' (I find the naming confusing, why is that 'global' and other shaders are not?) and to make use of the Render Dependency Graph. I'm also aware that I'll probably need to do some work with deferred shading but really at this stage, I just want to prove out some simple things - just get a mesh rendering using direct draw calls or injected calls to the RDG and then see if I can upload structured buffers into the shader in a way that makes sense.

Is what I'm trying to do so far out of the normal flow of things that it's either impossible or impractical, am I asking the right questions and should I go about this in another way (please bear in mind that much of what I've said are requirements that define the task I have in front of me)

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since what you need is to do with vertex shader, you're gonna have to build your mesh, already, equipped with those extra resources. This is done through customizing the vertex factory and defining your required inputs for the material of the mesh. So, you're gonna need to create a custom mesh component with a custom vertex factory through which you can pass/bind your vertex shader parameters. If you need to do more custom work for material, then you can also extend your material shader class and use it through your custom scene/mesh component.